# How can I write a function that transposes a musical note by a half step?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm building a guitar tuning application, and I've been stuck on achieving this.

I'm trying to write a function that takes a note, an octave, and a direction (up or down), and returns a transposed musical note by a half step, following a traditional piano layout (meaning shifting the note B to C will change octaves).

The function should support sharps as well.

i.e., here are some examples:

```
const noteShiftedHalfStepUp = pitchShiftNoteByHalfStep({note: "B", octave: 3}, "up")
console.log(noteShiftedHalfStepUp) // {note: "C", octave: 4}

const testCase2 = pitchShiftNoteByHalfStep({note:"G#", octave: 4}, "up")
console.log(testCase2) // {note: "A", octave: 4}

const testCase3 = pitchShiftNoteByHalfStep({note: "A#", octave: 4}, "down")
console.log(testCase3) // {note: "A", octave: 4}
```

I'm open to using libraries as well, but I couldn't find any that could help with this

Here is what I have so far:

```
function pitchShiftNoteByHalfStep(note, octave, direction) {
  const musicalNotes = [ 'A', 'A#', 'B', 'C', 'C#', 'D', 'D#', 'E', 'F', 'F#', 'G', 'G#'];

  const index = musicalNotes.indexOf(note);
  const newIndex = direction === 'up' ? index + 1 : index - 1;
  const newNote = musicalNotes[newIndex >= 0 ? newIndex : 11];

  const newOctave = (octave + Math.floor((newIndex + (direction === 'up' ? 0 : 11)) / 12));

  return `${newNote}${newOctave}`
}
```

It's breaking in a few edge cases, such as when i alter a note from G# up.

Thanks so much!

Comment: You can represent the notes as absolute values, where C0 is 0, C1 is 12, etc. Then it becomes a fairly simple matter of (Convert note name + octave to a number) -> Add or subtract 1 -> (Convert number back to a note name + octave). A dictionary of note name -> number, an array for number -> note name (starting at C), some integer division and modulo arithmetic will be useful here.

Comment: Interesting & unique approach!
I ended up figuring it out by a few if statements for the edge cases of when transposing the note from B to C, and from G# to A, etc

Comment: @RyanRoberts May I ask what happens from G# to A? Going up from G# should just return A, wo any octave shift, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some things to consider:

- As octaves start at **C** it will be easier to manage if you start the note names array with "C", not "A".
- Instead of passing "up" and "down", pass a signed integer, which would be 1 for *up*, -1 for *down*, but which allows you to also add more than one half note in one go.
- Use the remainder operator (`%`) to facilitate the calculation.

```js
const NOTES = "C,C#,D,D#,E,F,F#,G,G#,A,A#,B".split(",");

function pitchShift({note, octave}, add) {
    const offset = NOTES.indexOf(note) + octave * 12 + add,
          noteNum = offset % 12;
    if (offset < 0 || offset >= 8*12) return null; // Indication of out-of-range.
    return {note: NOTES[noteNum], octave: (offset - noteNum) / 12};
}

// demo
let pitch = {note: "C", octave: 4};
console.log(JSON.stringify(pitch));
// Add 4 half notes to arrive at E:
pitch = pitchShift(pitch, 4);
console.log(JSON.stringify(pitch));
// Subtract 6 half notes to arrive at A# of previous octave
pitch = pitchShift(pitch, -6);
console.log(JSON.stringify(pitch));
// Add 3 half notes to arrive at C#:
pitch = pitchShift(pitch, 3);
console.log(JSON.stringify(pitch));
// Subtract 2 half notes to arrive at B:
pitch = pitchShift(pitch, -2);
console.log(JSON.stringify(pitch));
// Subtract to go to lowest pitch that is supported (C octave 0)
pitch = pitchShift(pitch, -47);
console.log(JSON.stringify(pitch));
// Subtract one more to get an out of range indication (null)
pitch = pitchShift(pitch, -1);
console.log(JSON.stringify(pitch));
// Define second-highest supported pitch (A# octave 7) and add 1 (B octave 7)
pitch = pitchShift({note: "A#", octave: 7}, 1);
console.log(JSON.stringify(pitch));
// Add one more to get an out of range indication (null)
pitch = pitchShift(pitch, 1);
console.log(JSON.stringify(pitch));
```

Comment: Absolutely elegant solution. Thanks!

Can I ask how you would go about adding validation such that the octaves don't surpass 7 or go below 0?

Comment: Sure. I updated the answer with code that performs a limit check, and it the result is out of range, `null` is returned instead of an object. A few tests were added at the end to demonstrate this feature.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another take on this:

```
function pitchShiftNoteByHalfStep(note, octave, direction) {
    const musicalNotes = ['A', 'A#', 'B', 'C', 'C#', 'D', 'D#', 'E', 'F', 'F#', 'G', 'G#'];
    const index = musicalNotes.indexOf(note);
    const newIndex = (musicalNotes.length + index + (direction === 'up' ? 1 : - 1)) % musicalNotes.length;
    const newNote = musicalNotes[newIndex];

    let octaveOffset = 0
    if (newIndex === 0 && direction === 'up') {
        octaveOffset = 1
    }
    if (newIndex === musicalNotes.length - 1 && direction === 'down') {
        octaveOffset = -1
    }

    const newOctave = octave + octaveOffset

    return `${newNote}${newOctave}`
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be the musical layman in me, but when you sort the notes in the array as they are on the piano your code should work regarding the octave shifting. The other answers look so overly complicated that I feel I missed something. But maybe it is of help.

```
const musicalNotes = ['C', 'C#', 'D', 'D#', 'E', 'F', 'F#', 'G', 'G#', 'A', 'A#', 'B'],
      maxOctave = 4,
      minOctave = 1;

function pitchShiftNoteByHalfStep(note, octave, direction) {
  let index = musicalNotes.indexOf(note),
      newIndex;

  if ('up' === direction) {
    if (index + 1 === musicalNotes.length) {
      newIndex = 0;
      octave++;

      if (octave > maxOctave) {
        octave = maxOctave;
        console.log('Warning: Limitting to max octave.');
      }
    }
    else {
      newIndex = index + 1;
    }
  }
  else if ('down' === direction) {
    if (0 === index) {
      newIndex = musicalNotes.length - 1;
      octave--;
      if (octave < minOctave) {
        octave = minOctave;
        console.log('Warning: Resetting to min octave.');
      }
    }
    else {
      newIndex = index - 1;
    }
  }

  return musicalNotes[newIndex] + '' + octave;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my working solution, but if anyone has ways to optimize it, that would be awesome!

```
export function pitchShiftNote(
  noteItem: INoteItem,
  direction: IPitchShiftDirection
): INoteItem {
  if (isInvalidInput(noteItem, direction)) {
    return noteItem;
  }

  const newNote = getTransposedNote(noteItem, direction);
  const newOctave = getTransposedOctave(noteItem, direction);

  return { note: newNote, octave: newOctave };
}

const getTransposedNote = (
  noteItem: INoteItem,
  direction: IPitchShiftDirection
): IMusicalNote => {
  const { note } = noteItem;
  if (note === 'G#' && direction === 'up') return 'A';
  if (note === 'A' && direction === 'down') return 'G#';

  const index = musicalNotes.indexOf(note);
  if (direction === 'up') return musicalNotes[index + 1];
  return musicalNotes[index - 1];
};

const getTransposedOctave = (
  noteItem: INoteItem,
  direction: IPitchShiftDirection
): IOctave => {
  const { note, octave } = noteItem;
  if (note === 'B' && direction === 'up') {
    return (octave + 1) as IOctave;
  }
  if (note === 'C' && direction === 'down') {
    return (octave - 1) as IOctave;
  }
  return octave;
};

const isInvalidInput = (
  noteItem: INoteItem,
  direction: IPitchShiftDirection
): boolean => {
  const { note, octave } = noteItem;
  if (note === 'A' && octave === 0 && direction === 'down') {
    console.warn('Note is the lowest in the register!');
    return true;
  }
  if (note === 'G#' && octave === 7 && direction === 'up') {
    console.warn('Note is the highest in the register!');
    return true;
  }
  return false;
};
```

My constants and types for reference:

```
type IMusicalNote = (typeof musicalNotes)[number];
type IOctave = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7;

interface INoteItem {
  note: IMusicalNote;
  octave: IOctave;
}

type IPitchShiftDirection = 'up' | 'down';
const musicalNotes = [ 'A', 'A#', 'B', 'C', 'C#', 'D', 'D#', 'E', 'F', 'F#', 'G', 'G#'] as const;
```